# Obteniendo valores de un json en js

Tags: javascript, json

necesito guardar los dato que estoy recibiendo de un **json** para esta ocasión necesito guarda todos los datos que estoy obteniendo en distintras variables, es decir por dato necesito crear una variable nueva que la contenga ...
tengo más o menos la idea. Supongo...

```js
var r = "json";
var datos = (Object.values(Object.values(Object.values(r)[1])[0])[1]);
for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {


  if (Object.values(datos[i])[0] == 1) {
    // guardar en variables de está posición 
  } else if (Object.values(datos[i])[0] == 2) {
    // guardar en variables de está posición 
  } else {
    cantidadNull++;
  }
}
```

```js
{
  "DatosEnvio": {},
  "DatosEnvioJson": {
    "Table1": {
      "campos": ["Column1", "total"],
      "datos": [{
        "Column1": 1956,
        "total": 1
      }, {
        "Column1": 1963,
        "total": 2
      }, {
        "Column1": 1966,
        "total": 1
      }, {
        "Column1": 1967,
        "total": 2
      }, {
        "Column1": 1968,
        "total": 1
      }, {
        "Column1": 1969,
        "total": 3
      }, {
        "Column1": 1970,
        "total": 2
      }, {
        "Column1": 1971,
        "total": 2
      }, {
        "Column1": 1972,
        "total": 3
      }, {
        "Column1": 1973,
        "total": 3
      }, {
        "Column1": 1974,
        "total": 1
      }, {
        "Column1": 1975,
        "total": 2
      }, {
        "Column1": 1976,
        "total": 1
      }, {
        "Column1": 1977,
        "total": 8
      }, {
        "Column1": 1978,
        "total": 2
      }, {
        "Column1": 1979,
        "total": 8
      }, {
        "Column1": 1980,
        "total": 6
      }, {
        "Column1": 1981,
        "total": 9
      }, {
        "Column1": 1982,
        "total": 8
      }, {
        "Column1": 1983,
        "total": 3
      }, {
        "Column1": 1984,
        "total": 3
      }, {
        "Column1": 1985,
        "total": 7
      }, {
        "Column1": 1986,
        "total": 6
      }, {
        "Column1": 1987,
        "total": 4
      }, {
        "Column1": 1988,
        "total": 8
      }, {
        "Column1": 1989,
        "total": 15
      }, {
        "Column1": 1990,
        "total": 8
      }, {
        "Column1": 1991,
        "total": 4
      }, {
        "Column1": 1992,
        "total": 9
      }, {
        "Column1": 1993,
        "total": 6
      }, {
        "Column1": 1994,
        "total": 8
      }, {
        "Column1": 1995,
        "total": 4
      }, {
        "Column1": 1996,
        "total": 4
      }, {
        "Column1": 1999,
        "total": 1
      }]
    },
    "Table2": {
      "campos": ["bandera", "mensaje"],
      "datos": [{
        "bandera": 0,
        "mensaje": "Se ingresaron los datos correctamente"
      }]
    }
  },
  "tablas": null,
  "bandera": "0",
  "mensaje": "--"
}
```

Como siempre agradezco infinitamente su ayuda, los amo :D

Comment: ¿Te referís a que querés tener una variable por cada año?

Comment: a cada año y el total

Comment: No entiendo la finalidad que buscas, ya que si querés trabajar con esos valores, ya los tenés en el json. Tal vez si explicás un poco más lo que buscás, te podremos ayudar más :)

Comment: Necesito todos esos valores de json pararlos a otras variables o manejar esos valor de forma independiente , los necesito para graficarlos con chart.js

Answer (score 0):

Si estás trabajando con chartjs seguro necesitas los arrays para obtener los datos para el label y otro para los resultados asociados a esos labels. Para esto, a partir del json que tenés, podes generar esos array de la siguiente forma:

```
//Array para guardar los años.
var column1 = [];
//Array para guardar los totales.
var total = []
var datos = (Object.values(Object.values(Object.values(mjson)[1])[0])[1]);
for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {

  column1.push(Object.values(datos[i])[0]);
  total.push(Object.values(datos[i])[1]);

}
//Mostrar los array's. El primer array supongo que podes usarlo para los labels de tu gráfico, y el segundo para los datos.
console.log(column1);
console.log(total);
```

Después sólo tenés que pasar esos array para gráficar con chartjs. No es necesario tener una variable por cada atributo.

```js
var mjson = {
  "DatosEnvio": {},
  "DatosEnvioJson": {
    "Table1": {
      "campos": ["Column1", "total"],
      "datos": [{
        "Column1": 1956,
        "total": 1
      }, {
        "Column1": 1963,
        "total": 2
      }, {
        "Column1": 1966,
        "total": 1
      }, {
        "Column1": 1967,
        "total": 2
      }, {
        "Column1": 1968,
        "total": 1
      }, {
        "Column1": 1969,
        "total": 3
      }, {
        "Column1": 1970,
        "total": 2
      }, {
        "Column1": 1971,
        "total": 2
      }, {
        "Column1": 1972,
        "total": 3
      }, {
        "Column1": 1973,
        "total": 3
      }, {
        "Column1": 1974,
        "total": 1
      }, {
        "Column1": 1975,
        "total": 2
      }, {
        "Column1": 1976,
        "total": 1
      }, {
        "Column1": 1977,
        "total": 8
      }, {
        "Column1": 1978,
        "total": 2
      }, {
        "Column1": 1979,
        "total": 8
      }, {
        "Column1": 1980,
        "total": 6
      }, {
        "Column1": 1981,
        "total": 9
      }, {
        "Column1": 1982,
        "total": 8
      }, {
        "Column1": 1983,
        "total": 3
      }, {
        "Column1": 1984,
        "total": 3
      }, {
        "Column1": 1985,
        "total": 7
      }, {
        "Column1": 1986,
        "total": 6
      }, {
        "Column1": 1987,
        "total": 4
      }, {
        "Column1": 1988,
        "total": 8
      }, {
        "Column1": 1989,
        "total": 15
      }, {
        "Column1": 1990,
        "total": 8
      }, {
        "Column1": 1991,
        "total": 4
      }, {
        "Column1": 1992,
        "total": 9
      }, {
        "Column1": 1993,
        "total": 6
      }, {
        "Column1": 1994,
        "total": 8
      }, {
        "Column1": 1995,
        "total": 4
      }, {
        "Column1": 1996,
        "total": 4
      }, {
        "Column1": 1999,
        "total": 1
      }]
    },
    "Table2": {
      "campos": ["bandera", "mensaje"],
      "datos": [{
        "bandera": 0,
        "mensaje": "Se ingresaron los datos correctamente"
      }]
    }
  },
  "tablas": null,
  "bandera": "0",
  "mensaje": "--"
};
//Array para guardar los años.
var column1 = [];
//Array para guardar los totales.
var total = []
var datos = (Object.values(Object.values(Object.values(mjson)[1])[0])[1]);
for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {

  column1.push(Object.values(datos[i])[0]);
  total.push(Object.values(datos[i])[1]);
 
}
//Mostrar los array's. El primer array supongo que podes usarlo para los labels de tu gráfico, y el segundo para los datos.
console.log(column1);
console.log(total);
```